# Why is the button click not working in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser, undetected-chromedriver

why doesn't the applied button (button.click()) work in the code?

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

def press_button():
    driver = uc.ChromeOptions()
    driver.headless=True
    driver.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=driver)
    driver.get('https://kad.arbitr.ru/')
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        inn_field = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="sug-participants"]/div/textarea')
        inn_field.send_keys('772000581641')
        button = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@type="submit"]')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)

    except:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    press_button()
```

at the same time, the inn_field field is filled in correctly. Also, if I'm not doing all this in headless mode, then everything goes fine ...
[image: dom data of html page for submit button]

Comment: Can you share dom data of html page for submit button?

Comment: @KetanPardeshi I have attached a screenshot to the question with dom data of html page for submit button

Answer (score 0):

In case this code works in regular mode but doesn't work in headless more probably the issue is that you didn't define screen size for headless mode.
The default screen size in headless mode is much smaller than the default screen size in regular mode.
So, try adding this line `options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")`.
Also, it is much better to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits than hardcoded sleeps.
And finally `//*[@type="submit"]` is not a unique locator for that element but it still will work since the button you trying to click is the first match for this XPath. But still, you should always use unique locators. This is a unique locator for that button: `"//div[@class='b-form-submitters']//*[@type='submit']"`

Comment: I added `driver.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")`, changed `"//div[@class='b-form-submitters']//*[@type='submit']"` - but still the application doesn't work... i think the site somehow detects the headless mode and deactivates the button..

Comment: Well, to check that you will have to make a screenshot.

Comment: yes i did it... `inn_field.send_keys('772000581641')` this code works (the field is filled), nothing happens next

Comment: Is submit button appears on the screen and it is enabled?

Comment: yes...the button appears, but no action occurs ... and if i start without headless mode, then the button is pressed ...

Comment: I can't debug that. But can you put `time.sleep(1)` after `inn_field.send_keys('772000581641')`, before `button = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@type="submit"]')` ?

Comment: I have already tried waiting 5 seconds before the button, it does not work... I keep thinking it's antibot protection